# Error in model.frame.default(formula = meansharelocal ~ meanshareglobal) : invalid type (list) for variable 'meansharelocal'

Tags: r, testing

Trying to conduct a t.test of two sets of data. The code I am writing for this is:

```
t.test(meansharelocal ~ meanshareglobal)
```

Each data set has 4 pieces of data, in a column like this in a table:

| mean(Share_1) | mean(Share_2) | mean(Share_3) | mean(Share_4) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.396552 | 1.034483 | 1.189655 | 1.396552 |

When I run `t.test(meansharelocal ~ meanshareglobal)` I receive this error.

> Error in model.frame.default(formula = meansharelocal ~
> meanshareglobal) :    invalid type (list) for variable
> 'meansharelocal'

Can someone tell me what is going wrong? I am trying to see if the two piece of data are statistically different enough.

This is what I got from Reprex, again, I am new to this so don't know if I accessed this wrong as it is coming up with more errors? But the only error I actually have is the last line!

```
globalshare <- global %>% mutate_at(c("Share_1", "Share_2", "Share_3", "Share_4"), funs(recode(.,"Extremely likely" = 4, "Somewhat likely" = 3, "Neither likely nor unlikely" = 2, "Somewhat unlikely" = 1, "Extremely unlikely" = 0)))
#> Error in tbl_vars_dispatch(x): object 'global' not found
  
localshare <- local %>% mutate_at(c("Share_1", "Share_2", "Share_3", "Share_4"), funs(recode(.,"Extremely likely" = 4, "Somewhat likely" = 3, "Neither likely nor unlikely" = 2, "Somewhat unlikely" = 1, "Extremely unlikely" = 0)))
#> Error in UseMethod("tbl_vars"): no applicable method for 'tbl_vars' applied to an object of class "function"

boxplot(globalshare$Share_1, globalshare$Share_2, globalshare$Share_3, globalshare$Share_4, 
        localshare$Share_1, localshare$Share_2, localshare$Share_3, localshare$Share_4, names=c
        ("Global1", "Global2", "Global3", "Global4", "Local1", "Local2","Local3", "Local4"))
#> Error in boxplot(globalshare$Share_1, globalshare$Share_2, globalshare$Share_3, : object 'globalshare' not found

meanshareglobal <- globalshare %>% summarise(mean(Share_1), mean(Share_2), mean(Share_3), mean(Share_4))
#> Error in summarise(., mean(Share_1), mean(Share_2), mean(Share_3), mean(Share_4)): object 'globalshare' not found

meansharelocal <- localshare %>% summarise(mean(Share_1), mean(Share_2), mean(Share_3), mean(Share_4))
#> Error in summarise(., mean(Share_1), mean(Share_2), mean(Share_3), mean(Share_4)): object 'localshare' not found

t.test(meanshareglobal ~ meansharelocal)
#> Error in eval(predvars, data, env): object 'meanshareglobal' not found
```

Comment: the data you have shown in your post does not have objects or columns named `meansharelocal` or `meanshareglobal`

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide a reprex

Comment: Sorry, the tables are called meansharelocal and meanshareglobal, each table layout is exactly as shown but with different figures. Not sure if that helps?  I am trying to compare the p-value of the comparison of all figures. @langtang

Comment: @Bruno , i am not sure if i have done it correctly, but have added it onto the main question? Sorry, I am very new to this!

Comment: So each of the two dataframes has 4 columns with n rows?

Comment: Yes, the one row sub row for the titles, and on the first row is the data, with the data spread across columns. @Lamma

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding from your comments correctly you have wide dataframes of 1 row. Assuming they are the same dimensions you can just transpose and bind them then do your t test.

```
t.globalshare  = t(globalshare)
t.localshare  = t(localshare)

combined = cbind(t.globalshare, t.localshare)

t.test(combined, t.globalshare ~ t.localshare)
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you! Turns out I was using ~ instead of , and now it works. Many thanks!

Comment: If this has solved your problem feel free to accept it as the answer.